# Grave accent / tilde console key

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently making a game, and I want to use the grave accent (`) or tilde (~) key for a certain keypress event. However I am unable to find the ConsoleKey for this specific character. ( I am referring to the key right under the Esc key)

If there is one, what is it's name?

And if it doesn't exist, is there a way to make my own? I tried doing this to make my own, however this leads into an error stating: `Error 1 The expression being assigned to 'tilde' must be constant`

```
const ConsoleKey tilde = (ConsoleKey) Convert.ToChar("`");
```

Currently I am dispatching my events like so:

```
// Fetch console keypress
ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

// Dispatch events
switch (key) {

    // Pause / resume
    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
        togglePause();
        break;

    // Debug mode
    // This is where I would like to use the ` or ~ console key.
    case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:
        toggleDebug();
        break;
}
```

Comment: "the grave accent (`) or tilde (~) key" - those are two distinct keys for me. Think about different keyboard layouts.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper On my keyboard they're both on the same key, under the escape key. As it is only for the developers it wouldn't matter if the players are unable to find the key.

Comment: That depends on the keyboard layout. For German keyboards, those two are far away from each other.

Comment: @ThomasW.  I am currently referring to the key under the escape key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

``` Convert.ToChar("``") ``` is not a constant expression. It is a method call that will be evaluated at runtime. Therefore the `const` keyword is not possible here.

Instead of converting the string to a char, you could use the char directly:

```
const ConsoleKey tilde = (ConsoleKey)'`';
```

However, simply casting is not a solution here I'd say. This would return `NumPad0` which is surely not what you expect.

The correct key is

```
ConsoleKey.Oem3
```

Comment: While Matthew was faster, this explains it a lot more. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I used a simple app to figure it out:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any Key:");
            while(true)
            {
                var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
                var key = keyInfo.Key;
                Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not obvious; here's the output:

```
Press any Key:
Oem3
```

So the tilde key is mapped to `ConsoleKey.Oem3`. I would have expected a "Tilde" enum value too.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to demonstrate the key required to do this:

```
case ConsoleKey.Oem3:
    Console.WriteLine("Found it");
    break;
```

This should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Ah works exactly as I was looking for! I will accept in 6 minutes

Comment: Should note too, your const statement didn't work because const variables are actually written to IL.  It needs to know at compile time the actual value, and Convert.ToChar is a function that gets called at runtime =D

Comment: "Try this" is not a good answer. Explain what was wrong with the code from OP and how your code fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

On a British keyboard the ` character is Oem8 (for me at least)